# How real-time apply works in logical standby oracle?

Tags: oracle, dataguard, standby

I am a little bit confused about real-time apply services.
I've read a documentation about the [services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/log_apply.htm#i1022811) and I still have a question.
Does archived redo logs required for logical standby or not?
I've configure logical standby and there are 3 destination for db_recovery_file dest.
1st is local storage, 2nd transmits logs on standby and the 3d is for switchover.
But still I do not purely understand how it works.
Please, clarify or give some useful links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does archived redo logs required for logical standby or not? 
>   Yes, it does.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/create_ls.htm#g105412

The archived redo logs (archivelogs, commonly) contain SQL statements to apply the changes being made to the database, as well as SQL statements to undo the work if a rollback occurs later on the primary's activity.

Comment: So, the achieved redo logs transmits to the standby and RFS processes writing redo data to the standby redo logs to apply changes to the dataguard. Am I correct?

Comment: The redo logs (their own specific thing) become archived logs on the primary. The archived logs get shipped to your 3 locations. The archived log is then opened and read by the logical standby to apply the database changes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.